# Почему скрипты подключаются в другом порядке?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-babel

Установил jquery и bootstrap с помощью npm, чтобы отказаться от bower:

```
npm i jquery bootstrap --save
```

Пытаюсь собрать такой скрипт:

```js
import 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap';

$( document ).ready( function () {
    console.log('Start!');
} );
```

Gulp таск:

```js
gulp.src( './ja/app.js' )
    .pipe( plugins.babel() )
    .pipe( plugins.browserify( {
        transform: [ 'babelify' ],
        insertGlobals: true,
        debug: true
    } ) )
    .pipe( plugins.uglify( {
        mangle: true,
        unused: true,
        showStack: true
    } ) )
    .pipe( gulp.dest( './build' ) );
```

И на выходе получается, что bootstrap включен первым. Соответственно получаем на странице ошибку: **Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined**

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import - пример `import jquery from 'jquery';`

Comment: Не сработало. Я уже как только не пробовал.

Answer (score 1):

Если кому интересно, то сработало только вот так:

```js
window.$ = window.jQuery = require( 'jquery' );
var Bootstrap = require( 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap' );
Bootstrap.$ = $;
```